# PHP stripslashes, intercepting MySQL SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a `BIG` script.

Each time something is added in the DB it applies `addslashes();`

The problem is that on selecting data from the DB it's not doing `stripslashes();`

This script is using the basic mysql driver.
I cannot edit any `SELECT` in the script because they are many and they are not in a centralized script but putted all over the script.

It could take ages for me to strip the slashes on every `SELECT`.
So I am wondering if there is a way to intercept every `SELECT` and strip the slashes from there..

I was having a look to https://www.php.net/override_function ,but I am not sure it's going to be useful.

Comment: if query is always assigned to a variable ex: $q = "SELECT ..."
you can try adding the stripslashes($q) to bottom of each statement

Answer (score 1):

> Each time something is added in the DB it applies addslashes();

You do this wrong. You should be using **proper** escaping method. `addslashes()` is NOT proper. i.e. for mysql it would be `mysql_real_escape_string()` (or `mysqli_....`)

> The problem is that on selecting data from the DB it's not doing stripslashes();

Of course it doesn't do it. It makes no sense for DB to do that so it is all fine.

> It could take ages for me to strip the slashes on every SELECT.

It is all because you do it all wrong. If you escape **special values** correctly (NOT the whole query), then you do not need to bother during reading. I got a feeling you do not understand why you need to escape in first place and you are trying to fix not really knowing what you are doing. Also note some DB helpers like PDO deal with escaping automatically, so you do not even need to bother.

Comment: This script has not been made by me and I am looking for a solution to fix the issues. Not just "you did it wrong", "you did it well". Thanks anyway